# Bash reading array in different format

Tags: bash

I use the below script to read the articles , and then display the articles.

```
echo " Please enter device no"
read -a articles
index=0
count=${#articles[@]}
echo "The number of articles are  $count"
while [ $index -lt $count ]
  do
    echo ${articles[$index]}
    index=$index+1
  done
```

But the issue is, I need to give articles via the spaces 
like `article1 article2 article3`?

Is there a way , I can input via comma like `article1, article2, article3`?

The array should accept in both ways ( Either comma OR spaces)?

Any pointers appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

`$index` cannot be incremented like that. Try using:

```
index=$((index+1))  # Universal shell (POSIX)
```

or

```
((index++))         # bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your own IFS before `read`

From `man Bash`

> **IFS** : The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting
>   after expansion and to split lines into  words  with  the  read 
>   builtin  command.   The  default  value  is `<space><tab><newline>`

```
$ IFS=' ,' read -a foo
cat dog sheep

$ printf '%s\n' ${foo[@]}
cat
dog
sheep

$ IFS=' ,' read -a foo
cat, dog, sheep

$ printf '%s\n' ${foo[@]}
cat
dog
sheep
```

Be sure to reset the IFS var to its default after that